# Table view first cell always same

Tags: ios, uitableview

well my issue is:

I want to have table view but I want to keep first cell always first , and never let it scroll
but other cells should scroll.

can someone please suggest me how to do so ?

Comment: For content not scrolling you should place that information into the tableview header.

Comment: Does it looks exactly as a regular cell ?and can be selected ?

Comment: As the dude said, if its a statics content cell means just use one header for the table that it.

Comment: @user2957713 You can use whichever view you want as header. Just use your cell view.

Comment: Oh , wow now I see that this objective-C is is powerful tool :)
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer with the static cell in the header works.

You might want to create another tableview just above the present one, with just static cells in it. Just below this table view, keep the present one with (number of all cells - number of static cells) without any offset. It looks as just one table view. This way, you can have more than one static cell with all the properties of a Tableview cell.

Comment: Than I will have to deal with 3 table views ))
so can you tell me how do I make it un-scrollable since 1 static cell still have some scroll animations :(

Comment: Scrolling can be disabled with tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO.

Comment: Right in time :)
Thanks you very much I implemented this method works fine , now disabling the scrolling :)

Comment: I put it in view did load where I allocating the table view but it still scrolls:(

Comment: same in cell per row :(

Answer (score 2):

If your table have only one section than create custom view like cell and add this view in 
table delegate method

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

like

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   return <Your View>
}
```

but it works if and only if one section in given in table.

Comment: but then I will have to draw the cell , and I also want it to be delgatable for selected cell in table view or whatever it called